# Adjust opacity of an image in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ImageChoose extends Application{   

ImageView myImageView;

public static void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
}     

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){

  final double MIN = 0.0, MAX = 1.0, INITIAL = .50;
  final double MAJOR_TICK_UNIT = .1;
  final int MINOR_TICK_COUNT = 1;
  final double SLIDER_WIDTH = 300.0;

  Button button = new Button("Search for Image");
  Slider slider = new Slider(MIN, MAX, INITIAL);
  slider.setMajorTickUnit(MAJOR_TICK_UNIT);
  slider.setMinorTickCount(MINOR_TICK_COUNT);
  slider.setShowTickMarks(true);
  slider.setShowTickLabels(true);
  slider.setSnapToTicks(true);
  slider.setPrefWidth(SLIDER_WIDTH);

  button.setOnAction(e ->
  {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterJPG = 
        new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("JPG files (*.JPG)", "*.JPG");
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterjpg = 
        new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("jpg files (*.jpg)", "*.jpg");
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterPNG = 
        new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PNG files (*.PNG)", "*.PNG");
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterpng = 
        new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("png files (*.png)", "*.png");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters()
        .addAll(extFilterJPG, extFilterjpg, extFilterPNG, extFilterpng);

    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);


       try {BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);
            Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);
            myImageView.setImage(image);
       } 
       catch (IOException ex) {

        Logger.getLogger(ImageChoose.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    });

    FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(1000),myImageView);


    slider.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldvalue, newvalue) ->{
           ft.setFromValue(oldvalue.doubleValue());
           ft.setToValue(newvalue.doubleValue());
           ft.play();
    });

    myImageView = new ImageView();  
    myImageView.setFitWidth(500);
    myImageView.setPreserveRatio(true);

    VBox vBox = new VBox(10);
    vBox.getChildren().addAll(button, slider, myImageView);
    vBox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
    Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 800, 800);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Opacity Adjuster");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    }
```

---

The purpose of this is to be able to choose an image file and adjust its opacity with a slider.

I am trying to adjust an image's opacity after choosing a file with opacity slider, but the opacity slider doesn't adjust the opacity of the image file I choose after moving the slider around. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to [set the node](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/FadeTransition.html#setNode(javafx.scene.Node)) onto which the transition should be applied:

```
    slider.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldvalue, newvalue) -> {
        ft.setFromValue(oldvalue.doubleValue());
        ft.setToValue(newvalue.doubleValue());
        ft.setNode(myImageView); //---> add this
        ft.play();
    });
```

So you are basically saying that when you change the slider, you want to record old value, get new value and then apply the transition on your image (ImageView, strictly speaking, since earlier in your code, you've set your node to `myImageView.setImage(image);`).

Answer (score 3):

One way to fix this is as per what @vs97 suggested. But the primary reason for your transistion not being worked because you are passing a null imageView and then creating the instance of ImageView. Create the imageView instance first and then pass it to transition. Also I would prefer to use playFromStart() rather than play() for a smooth effect.

```
        myImageView = new ImageView();
        myImageView.setFitWidth(500);
        myImageView.setPreserveRatio(true);

        // Create the transition after instantiating myImageView.
        FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(1000), myImageView);
        slider.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldvalue, newvalue) -> {
            ft.setFromValue(oldvalue.doubleValue());
            ft.setToValue(newvalue.doubleValue());
            ft.playFromStart();
        });
```